# How to restrict full_join() duplicates? - R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am a novice R programmer. Below is the dataframe I am using.
I am currently running into a filtering problem with the `full_join()` from `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
              trial = rep(0:1, each = 8),
              sex = rep(c('M','F'), 4),
              participant = rep(1:4, 4),
              x = runif(16, 1, 10),
              y = runif(16, 1, 10))

df
```

[image]

I am currently doing the following operation to do the `full_join()`

```
df <- df %>% mutate(k = 1)
df <- df %>% 
   full_join(df, by = "k")
```

I am restricting the results to obtain the combination of points for the same participant between the trials

```
df2 <- filter(df, sex.x == sex.y, participant.x == participant.y, trial.x != trial.y)
df3 <- filter(df2, participant.x == 1)
df3
```

[image]

Here, at this step, I am running into trouble. I do not care about the order of the points. How do I condense the duplicates into one row?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure how you are getting df <- df %>% full_join(df,by="k") to run. There is no "k" in df.

Comment: good catch! that line before the full_join command should be `df %>% mutate(k = 1)` EDIT: I'll make the edit on the question

Comment: So looking at your data, I am assuming that you want to condense the rows based on the duplicates seen in the first five columns. Is that right?

Comment: I may be repeating yourself. Essentially, the first 5 rows contain all the information I need because the ordering of the points does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the columns you are considering, use the duplicate function. The first one will weed out duplicates based on the first 5 columns. The last one will weed out duplicates based on

```
df3[!duplicated(df3[,1:5]),]

df3[!duplicated(df3[,7:11]),]
```

Comment: Took me awhile to understand the reasoning here. But, essentially, I want check the duplicated values in those columns because if I do i just recover all the unique unorder pairings.